# AutoMapper: How to configure opt.NullSubstitute on nested property?

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

I'm trying to set the NullSubstitute option on a nested property.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<JobRecord> JobRecords { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var jobRecords = _jobInfoService.GetAll().ToList();
    var viewModel = new HomeViewModel();

    Mapper.Map(jobRecords, viewModel);
    // Not sure how to properly map the nested property here

    return View(viewModel);
}

private static void CreateMapForHomeViewModel()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<List<JobRecord>, HomeViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.JobRecords, x => x.MapFrom(src => src));

    // Not sure if this is correct
    Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyInfo, CompanyInfo>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.CompanyName, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(""));
}
```

My understanding is that I would have to setup another configuration for the inner source/destination, set the NullSubstitute and then call Map; haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.